# Error while booting ubuntu 23

Tags: boot

Getting this error inconsistently-
Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0).

Sometimes it boots successfully and sometimes it throws this error.

I tried installing from different USBs , but no luck.

Any idea how to resolve this permanently ?

Comment: Ubuntu 23?   Ubuntu's main products are *year.month* in format, so do you mean Ubuntu 23.04?  or something else?  Are you using Ubuntu?  If you are using Ubuntu, did you verify the ISO, was it written correctly with updated software?  (*some older software can only write ISOs for releases up to 20.04 for example*)

Comment: Yes its 23.04, the error is very inconsistent. Sometimes Ubuntu gets booted and I can login and work on it. But if restart or shutdown and again try to login this error pops up. When I logged in, I checked for all software updates. Its correct. I even ran sudo apt-get update and updated it all.

Comment: This isn't a forum, your question still doesn't mention a release (*and any answers will be to your actual question, not subsequent comments made by readers about that question - this is a Q&A site remember*). Also be specific, 23.04 has many ISO choices using different installers and you've not yet said what 23 (.04) product you're asking about.  I'd have booted to *runlevel 1* and looked for clues in logs, have you?  Systemd journals survive reboot, though a failure to boot may leave few clues.